# "apt-get install Apache2" error

Tags: apt, apache2

I'm trying to install apache2 on my Kubuntu Linux using
        `sudo apt-get install apache2`
and it shows me this message:

```
dagger@HP:~$ sudo apt-get install apache2
       Reading package lists... Done
       Building dependency tree
       Reading state information... Done
       You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
       The following packages have unmet dependencies:
       apache2 : Depends: apache2-bin (= 2.4.18-2ubuntu3.1) but it is  
       not going to be installed
       Depends: apache2-utils (>= 2.4)
       Depends: apache2-data (= 2.4.18-2ubuntu3.1) but it is not going      
       to be installed
       google-chrome-stable : Depends: libappindicator1 but it is not 
       going to be installed
       E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no                 
       packages (or specify a solution).
       dagger@HP:~$ ^C
```

Comment: Have you tried taking the suggested action?

Comment: i'm gonna try theme right now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt update 
sudo apt full-upgrade
sudo apt install -f apache2
```

Answer (score 3):

Like the error message states, try:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Idf that's successful then:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```